# Why does AC/Sweep in Cadence always require a starting and stopping frequency?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, pspice, cadence

It seems as if there is no way to simply test a circuit with an AC voltage source at a single frequency.

How does someone test a circuit that plugs into the main voltage at 60Hz? Is it really mandatory that you account for every single frequency up to and including your source's intended frequency?

I'm angry at CADENCE!

Comment: Of course, it is possible in AC analyses to use a single frequency only. In this case, specify for example simply between 1k and 1k. But - for which purpose?? The main purpose of the ac run is to display magnitude and phase as a function of frequency,

Comment: I was getting errors when trying to run Time transient simulations with an AC voltage source in my schematic. It doesn't seem to be doing it anymore though. :^)

Comment: You cannot run a transient simulation with an AC voltage source. That`s unlogical! An AC source is for AC analyses only!! For a tran simulation in the time domain it seems logical to specify how the input should looks like (sinus or squarewave or....)

Comment: "*I'm angry at CADENCE!*", yes... I still have nightmares from using that.. monstrosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VAC source is for frequency analysis. You would want to use the VSIN source for time domain simulation.